# OpenCV (Python) Overlaying Canny Analysis Output onto the Original Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, overlay, canny-operator

In my current state I have a program which reads in an image and completes a Canny Analysis of the image using the OpenCV library in Python.

I need to be able to take the lines created and overlay them onto the original image for the user to see.

I've tried to remove the background of the image and then overlay that but it has not been successful.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check opencv’s `addWeighted` function

Comment: That does it, Cheers :)